# Reactjs/Javascript update object key name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to update object `key` name on setState. I have this object:

```
let obj = {
      sponsorship: {
        a: {
          task: "x",
          todo: "y"
        },
        b: {
          task: "x1",
          todo: "y2"
        }
      }
    };
    setForm(obj);
```

Now want to rename one of object key name:

```
setForm({
      ...form,
      sponsorship: {
        ...form.sponsorship,
        [newName]: { ...form.sponsorship[oldName] }
      }
    });
```

I tried this but it will add new object not replace. also tried this:

```
setForm({
      ...form,
      sponsorship: {
        [newName]: { ...form.sponsorship[oldName] }
      }
    });
```

But this will remove all prev object. but I need to for example rename `a` key to `c`

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-dust-zv87rx)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Comment: You need to manipulate the object just like you would do with any other JS object. Also it's preferable to use a callback when using the current state value to calculate the next one

Comment: Sometimes you can use `const { dontCare, ...doCare } = obj`, but not when the property name is dynamic. Create the new sponsorships argument, then delete the old name.

Comment: It might be easier if `sponsorship` was an array of objects instead.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't want to remove actually.. I know it's a way, but is there any way to rename? I want to do this in setState

Comment: That _is_ how you rename - add as new name, remove as old name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to delete a property and you are searching for an alternative way to do it, you can filter the `sponsorship` properties and return a new object without the `oldValue`

```
setForm({
  ...form,
  sponsorship: {
    ...Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(form.sponsorship)
      .filter(([key]) => oldName !== key)
    ),
    [newName]: { ...form.sponsorship[oldName] }
  }
});
```

Comment: Ideally when new value depends on the previous one you should pass a callback function which gets current state value as the first argument.

`setForm(state => {
      const {[oldName]: _oldKey, ...restSponsorship} = state.sponsorship;
      return {
      ...state,
      sponsorship: {
        ...restSponsorship,
        [newName]: { ...state.sponsorship[oldName] }
      }
    }});`